# Create a dictionary out of a list vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

i have a list with 2 columns (clm1=StoreID and clmn2=ProductID).
i need to loop through this list and create a dictionary(StoreID , List(of ProductID))
i am using vb.net . can you please help me with the loop i have to make?
The list data is something like

```
StoreID  ProductID
1          234
2          456
1          222
3          768
1          100
9          876
e.t.c.
```

Comment: Refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

Comment: Hi @sam1604 , i know how to use dictionaries but i can not figure out how to loop through my datatable entries to achive the result i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your data is stored somewhat like this:

```
Structure Item
    Public StoreID As Integer
    Public ProductID As Integer
End Structure

Dim l As List(Of Item)
```

Then you have two options. The first one is to create the dictionary by hand:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))
For Each item As Item In l
    Dim subList As List(Of Integer)
    Dim keyExists = dictionary.TryGetValue(item.StoreID, subList)
    If keyExists Then
        subList.Add(item.ProductID)
    Else
        subList = New List(Of Integer)
        subList.Add(item.ProductID)
        dictionary.Add(item.StoreID, subList)
    End If
Next
```

Here, you just iterate all items. Check the dictionary if it already contains an entry for the store id. If so, just add the product id. If not, create an entry and then add the product id.

If you're not overly concerned with performance, you can use the following LINQ expression to create the dictionary:

```
Dim dictionary = l.GroupBy(Function(item) item.StoreID) _
                  .ToDictionary(Function(group) group.Key, _
                                Function(group) group.Select(Function(item) item.ProductID) _
                                                     .ToList())
```

You first group the elements by their `StoreID`. Then, the `ToDictionary()` method creates the dictionary. It takes two parameters. The first one is a function that specifies the key of each element. In this case, we want to use the group's key as the dictionary key (which is the store id). The second parameter is the value that is inserted in the dictionary. First, we use `Select` to map each `Item` to its `ProductID` (because we want to store product ids and not entire items. Then we call `ToList()` to generate a list from the items in the group.